# LightWallet: Empty array for (await api.getUsedAddresses() || await api.getUnusedAddresses() || [])

Tags: nami, ccvault, cip30, lightwallet, eternl

I am working on a light wallet integration. The recommended way of integrating with wallets is defined in CIP30.

When I select Nami and call:
`(await api.getUsedAddresses() || await api.getUnusedAddresses() || [])`
everything works fine and I receive at least one wallet address - a non empty array. But using the same code for eternl/ ccvault I always receive an empty array.

Is this a missing implementation error on their end or a mistake on my end?
`getChangeAddress()` works fine for both wallets.

Here some code snippets for more context:

```
export const isBrowser = () => typeof window !== "undefined";
export type Cardano = {
  [key: string]: {
    name: string;
    icon: string;
    version: string;
    api?: WalletApi,
    enable: () => Promise<WalletApi>;
    isEnabled: () => Promise<boolean>;
  };
};

export const getCardano = (): Cardano | undefined => {
  const cardano = isBrowser() && window.cardano;
  return cardano;
};
```

and then later in the app:

```
async (actions, target, { getStoreActions }) => {
      const walletName: string = target.payload;
      const cardano = getCardano()!;
      const api = await cardano[walletName]!.enable();
      const addresses = (await api.getUsedAddresses()
                      || await api.getUnusedAddresses()
                      || []);
{...}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Marcel - founder of eternl I've found my mistake.

`await api.getUsedAddresses()` actually returns an empty array - I thought both calls return `undefined` and it defaults to `[]`.

After calling `await api.getUsedAddresses()` and `await api.getUnusedAddresses()` separately they both work as expected since my test wallet currently does not have used addresses.